# Tooling API query unknown exception

Tags: query, exception, tooling-api

While these queries work:

```
select Name from StandardAction where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account'
select Name from StandardAction where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Asset'
```

these queries don't work:

```
select Name from StandardAction where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName in ('Account', 'Asset')
select Name from StandardAction where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account' or EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Asset'
```

Error:

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION
>
> [object Object]: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 452578031-206493 (1257218050)

Any ideas on how to efficiently workaround this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't run queries on this object so far.. but looking at the [EntityDefinition object definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) SOQL Limits section, it seems only equals operator is supported on this object

Example Query:

```
SELECT qualifiedapiname FROM EntityDefinition WHERE qualifiedapiname!='Account'
```

> Error Returned: Only equals comparisons permitted

as mentioned by San in the comment, the **In** operator is **working** on the EntityDefinition when we query the object **directly**.

```
SELECT qualifiedapiname FROM EntityDefinition WHERE qualifiedapiname in ('Account','Case')
```

but it's **not working** when you do the **cross object query** between StandardAction and EntityDefinition.

so as a workaround what you can do is get all the Id

```
/services/data/v34.0/tooling/query?q=select+Id+from+EntityDefinition+where+QualifiedApiName+in+('Account','case')
```

and then use the In clause on EntityDefinitionId by passing in the ids.

```
/services/data/v34.0/tooling/query?q=select+Name+from+StandardAction+where+EntityDefinitionId+in+('4ie9xxxxx','4ie9xxxx')
```

I just tried this in Workbench REST Explorer and its working fine.

Comment: We can use IN operator to compare more than one value.

Comment: This seems viable. Thanks! However, if the equals operator is the only supported comparison on `QualifiedApiName` why does my 4th query not work? I am pairing equals with OR.. This API is weird.

Comment: the same limits section has the details for OR as well.